# How can I get the class of a parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to find the `class` of the parent element of the child with `.current`.

```js
var currentli = $('.nav').find('a.current').parent().attr('class');
console.log(currentli);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab1">
      <a href="#1" class="current">Welcome</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2">
      <a href="#2">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- and some lists more -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

but it always throws me `undefined`

**NOTE:** I don't know which `a` currently has `.current` which is why I have to use the `.find()` method.

Comment: Your code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/FSGpz/ -- `tab1` is logged

Comment: Are you running this within a document ready call?

Comment: guys thanks, it seems that i corrected the code myself by typing this question here. @tymeJV it works absolutely correct! thanks anyways to you!

Comment: Voting to close as too-localized, because there wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your code should already work, but it might be more reliable to access the property `className` instead:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  console.log($('.nav a.current').parent().prop('className'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab1">
      <a href="#1" class="current">Welcome</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2">
      <a href="#2">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- and some lists more -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
var currentli = $($('.nav').find('a.current')).parent().attr('class');
console.log(currentli);
```

I'm simply transforming the found collection into a jQuery object again.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/wnW4u/

Ps.: If more than one `a` has `class="current"`, only the first one will be retrieved.

Comment: `.find()` definitely returns a jQuery object, and you can definitely chain it. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @nnnnnn true true. Standalone `$.find()` that does return an array object.

Comment: What is "standalone `$.find()`"? Do you have a link to some doco? (Regardless, that's not what the OP is using.)

Comment: @nnnnnn You can use `.find` in two ways: `$('someSelector').find('selector to be found inside someSelector')` [API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or by using `$.find('whatever')`. I can't find the page for `jQuery.find` on jquery.com anymore, but here is a test case: http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/Cdre7/ On the first IS a **jQuery object**, while the second (`$.find()`) is a **JS Object** *(an array with elements and not a jQuery Object)* therefore none of jQuery API works e.g., `css()`, `attr()` etc etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn The page for `jQuery.find` WAS http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.find/ but does not exist :-/ By the way, updated fiddle with comments. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/Cdre7

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  console.log($('.nav a.current').parent().prop('className'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab1">
      <a href="#1" class="current">Welcome</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2">
      <a href="#2">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- and some lists more -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see this thread before adding an answer: [How do I write good answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)